# How to estimate Residuals of Autoregressive Model AR(2)with missing data for dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, multiple-columns, quantmod

I want to estimate/acquire residuals of AR(2) model. As residuals =Actual value- Fitted value.I have a huge dataframe with 4000 columns (company in each), time series. Now I want to run a AR(2) model and get the residuals from it.These columns are a liquidity measure of each company. Now I need to transform this liquidity measure that has been calculated for each company to be transformed  by Auto Regressive model with 2 lags,so, that first auto correlation is removed.To transform the liquidity measure for each company using AR(2) process outlined in below equation and use residuals for subsequent analysis.

[image]

Where, Ct i is a measure of liquidity for stock i at month t, x is the number of lags included in the autoregressive process, and ut i is the residuals in liquidity for stock i at month t. 
 I provide a small part of my data as below.

```
 DATE         A     B   C       D   E   F
31/12/1999  79.5    NA  NA      6   NA  NA
03/01/2000  79.5    NA  NA      6   NA  NA
04/01/2000  79.5    NA  325     6   961 3081.9
05/01/2000  79.5    NA  322.5   6   945 2524.7
06/01/2000  79.5    NA  327.5   6   952 3272.3
07/01/2000  79.5    NA  327.5   6   941 2102.9
10/01/2000  79.5    7   327.5   6   946 2901.5
11/01/2000  79.5    7   327.5   6   888 9442.5
12/01/2000  79.5    7   331.5   6   870 7865.8
13/01/2000  79.5    7   334     6   853 7742.1
```

I have from stats package found out this code as below. Could you please help specify this code,so, that it runs for each column(except date) and take care of missing values while having a lag of 2.

```
ar(x, aic = TRUE, order.max = NULL,
   method = c("yule-walker", "burg", "ols", "mle", "yw"),
   na.action, series, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is called `df` you can add the residuals of AR(2) models for each column as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(df, apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) arima(x, order = c(2,0,0))$res))
df
       Date   Company1   Company2   Company1.1    Company2.1
1  Jan-2000 0.05365700 0.01821019 -0.036876374  0.0006985845
2  Feb-2000 0.07201239 0.01680506 -0.001093970 -0.0005063298
3  Mar-2000 0.08740745 0.01924687 -0.003796628  0.0017217050
4  Apr-2000 0.10866274 0.01792439  0.010745400  0.0007815183
5  May-2000 0.14189171 0.01848372  0.032286719  0.0014418422
6  Jun-2000 0.15228030 0.01472494  0.023719800 -0.0024127538
7  Jul-2000 0.10231285 0.01634404 -0.025709302 -0.0016760248
8  Aug-2000 0.10838209 0.01919361  0.019162611  0.0009089139
9  Sep-2000 0.08358543 0.01624093 -0.022191184 -0.0010003877
10 Oct-2000 0.10907866 0.01768522  0.022780332  0.0001924767
```

Edited code:

```
df <- data.frame(df, apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) arima(x[!is.na(x)], order = c(2,0,0), method = "ML")$res))
```

Comment: Will this result in new dataframe?

Comment: What would you like to habe in the dataframe? Fitted values?

Comment: I want to use the residuals from the AR(2) of each column(company) for the subsequent analyses in my study.

Comment: Pardon me if it's a lame question. But if it's AR (2) then shouldn't the Jan and Feb be absent?

Comment: I think the first fitted values / residuals are recursively estimated using the Kalman filter

Comment: Let me study about this and then I will accept your answer. I hope you understand.

Comment: could you please tell me which package you used here.

Comment: I receive this erro `Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : non-finite value supplied by optim `

Comment: Could you please help me tackle the missing value in the code that you have provided.

Comment: @Aquarius You can remove the missing values beforehand, e.g.: `df <- na.omit(df)`

Comment: That's the major problem. My sample set (dataset) is bit complex. I have companies that are and have been listed at stock exchange. So, if Co.  A was listed in 2000 while Co. B was listed 2003 so, there would be all Nas for B before 2003. I would really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: Then try using `x[!is.na(x)]` instead of `x` in the `arima` call.

Comment: I receive error `Error: unexpected symbol in "Adf <- data.frame(A, apply(A[-1], 2, function(x) arima(x[!is.na(x)] order"`

Comment: I receive `Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim `

Comment: Is it possible to change method to Maximum Likelihood. I really apprecaite your guidence.

Comment: Please read the help to the used functions. If you look at `?arima` you can see that you can set `method = "ML"`

Comment: I realize its bit of a stretch. But your code is real close to what I want. Could you please make changes to the code that you provided in the anwer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101109/discussion-between-aquarius-and-dataminer).

Comment: I receive error ` Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim `. I'm stuck.

Comment: @Aquarius Maybe you should try another methods? A reproducible example would help...

Comment: I try to provide reproducible example.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Aquarius In your 9. and 10. coulumns you only have one value which is not `NA`. This causes your error...

Comment: I have removed columns that have less that 2 values and rest NAs but still receive error.

Comment: I receive `In addition: Warning messages:
1: In arima(x, order = c(2, 0, 0)) :
  possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1
2: In summary.lm(fit) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable`

Comment: Is this a way not get the duplicates because we get original column and residual column of that company. I mean for example co.A and residual co.A.1. Is it possible to get only residual columns.

Comment: It has been a while now, but could you suggest how to get R square for this?